# How to debug flutter unit test?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to tap a `FlatButton` I have a lot on the screen but they all have unique `Key`s. I have a `print` as the only line in the `onPressed` function.

This is working, I see the printed line in the console:

```
expect(find.byKey(Key('q1a2')), findsOneWidget);
await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('q1a2')));
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

This is not working, I do not see the printed line in the console:

```
expect(find.byKey(Key('q3a2')), findsOneWidget);
await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('q3a2')));
await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

The `expect` passes in both examples. How can I go about debugging this?

The `FlatButton` widget code:

```
FlatButton(
  key: Key('q${questionId}a$score'),
  color: isSelected ? Colors.amberAccent : Colors.transparent,
  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  splashColor: Colors.amberAccent.withOpacity(0.2),
  shape: CircleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(
      color: isSelected ? Colors.amberAccent : Colors.grey[300],
      width: 1.0
    )
  ),
  onPressed: () {
    print('WTF!');
  },
  child: Text(
    score.toString(),
    style: TextStyle(
      color: isSelected ? Colors.grey[900] : Colors.grey[600],
      fontSize: isSelected ? 20.0 : 18.0,
      fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.normal : FontWeight.w300
    )
  )
),
```

Comment: Dear @Justin808,
Hello,
A wonderful and amazing new day for all the World :)

Did you find out something more about this issue?